# Compressed image is not going to save using angular js

Tags: angularjs, django, django-forms, django-angular

I am trying to compress multiple images using angular js, It also showing compressed images before submitting the button but after uploading those images they are going to save with original size but not of compressed size in database

What corrections are needed? plz help...

```
<body ng-app="angNewsApp">
<form method='POST' action='/dashboard/ti/' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
{% csrf_token %}
    <div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
        <h2>Multiple</h2>
        <input id="inputImage" name="file" type="file" accept="image/*" ng-model="imageList" image="imageList" resize-max-height="800" resize-max-width="800" resize-quality="0.7" resize-type="image/jpg" multiple="multiple" ng-image-compress/>
        <div>
            <img ng-src="{% verbatim %}{{item.compressed.dataURL}}{% endverbatim %}" ng-repeat="item in imageList" />
        </div>

    </div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


</body>
```

here is [demo](http://oukan.github.io/angular-image-compress/) that what i am doing. and now i want save these images to database but original are going... What to do?

Comment: can you post ur view, url and form

Comment: @c.grey hello but main problem is here now

Comment: what have you tried need to know

Comment: @c.grey i implemented that demo in django as above and linking those js files as given in that demo's source code Now it working like as demo but those compressed images are not going to save in database, original images are saving in database..Iwant to save those compressed images.